# Starting sharepoint 2007 workflows simultaneously on list items using Timer job

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

I am trying to programmatically start a workflow on multiple items simultaneously of a sharepoint 2007 list, I have found code to start workflow programmatically but the issue is, The workflows don't start simultaneously, that is the workflow starts, completes and then only proceeds to start the next workflow.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
{
   item["timerJobInitiated"] = "Yes";
   item.Update();
   SPListItem wrkItem = list.GetItemById(item.ID);
   wrkflowmgr.StartWorkflow(wrkItem , wflassociation,wflassociation.AssociationData);
}
```

Comment: please provide a bit more information what the timer job does and what "timerJobInitiated" is.

Comment: The workflow transfer files between locations, The "timerJobintitated field is set to yes, to let the workflow know that the instance is started by timer job and not Manually. Basically i have tried removing the updation of timerjobintitated, even then the issue persists. I am wondering if i should set the status of my workflow in code to be Started at workflowactivated method . Because in my code as of now , i dont change the status / state of workflow and let sharepoint handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this using multitasking, by starting workflows in threads. This provided the desired functionality. I have updated the entire code [here](http://www.godwinpaul.com/sharepoint/2014/programatically-start-sharepoint-2007-workflows-simultaneously-on-list-items-using-timer-job) as its too long to be posted here.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information and maybe a code example on how you solved the issue so that it is helpful to others with the same problem. After that accept your own answer, which is fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly used the `StartWorkflow` method - there is no **simultaneous** method to start workflows for multiple list items at the same time. You can only start them one list item after another.

You write now that the workflow completes and only then the next workflow starts - that shouldn't happen. Could you clarify a bit, I would update this answer then?

Comment: The workflow starts and the workflow status of the Item changes to In Progress , however the next item in loop where the workflow should start doesnt change until the In Progress of the previous item changes to Completed. Its a sequential workflow on the list which i am trying to start from Custom Timer Job.